# How to find out where a script-tag has been defined in the wordpress-header?

Tags: wordpress

I have to work in a wordpress project of a former colleague. But I cannot figure out how he added an link-address to a script into the header of each page. After a global search, the link-address was found inside the sql dump of the wordpress project. I could not find any plugin he might have used. I would like to change the link-address. Any idea, how he added it?

```
<script src="http://custom-link/page.js" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

Comment: Hi, regarding the question you just deleted: sorry for the flood of completely useless comments. That was hard to watch. Anyway, a) you can store `<p>...</p>` (without quotes!) in a js object directly because you're using React b) to render html strings you need https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml (still, your question was not 100% clear)

Answer (score 1):

It was added by the wordpress plugin divi builder.

```
Divi Theme Options
To add a code to every page navigate to Divi Theme Options > Integration tab.  
Make sure the “Enable header code” option is checked, and paste your code below.
```